# Print "incorrect login" only after password step + change "root" username

Tags: linux, printing, login

I'm on Centos 7, and I need to do 2 things:

1. By default, "incorrent login" prints right after login step, for example, when I enter non-existent login, but I need full authentification: login step -> password step -> "incorrect login" OR successful login
2. I need to change "root" username to another for using it in system login

Does anyone have an idea, how to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (1) Your "2 things" should be two separate questions. (2) I don't believe that '"incorrent login" prints right after login step' in a tty or via SSH, so probably you described some specific situation (display manager?). Please clarify. (3) See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For your first question please clearify you want to change authentication behavior for ssh or tty!
For your second question you should create new user and give root privilage to that and then disable root logi; Here are the steps:

```
sudo adduser username
sudo usermod -aG wheel username
sudo passwd username
visudo
new_username ALL=(ALL) ALL
sudo passwd -l root
```